# How to hide vertical scrollbar for multiple image containers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I want to have a container that has multiple vertical images that go off the screen which can be scrolled up/down. I also want the scrollbar to be hidden. An example is here: https://www.calm.com/

Does anyone know how I can do this (preferably without JavaScript?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/5GCsJ/954/)

```
#parent{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#child{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```